# How to refresh UITextFields and UILabels in a static Table with a UIButton

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a static tableView in a UITableViewController. The static table is populated with UITextfields and UILabels where the user would input their data into the UITextFields and after pressing a "calculate" UIButton it creates an answer in the UILabels.

How do i create a UIButton that clears all the data on the static table?

I have managed to do this using self.loadView() but i know i shouldn't be doing that.

I have also managed to do this by setting each UITextFields and UIlabels to an empty string when the UIButton is pressed, but I'm aware this is bad practice and that there must be a cleaner and simpler way.

I want one UIButton which is a UIBarButtonItem that when pressed, clears all the UITextFields and UILabels back to before they were populated and before the calculated results.

Comment: What happens if you just tell the table view to `reloadData()`? The labels and text fields were empty when the table view came from the storyboard, so you'd think that would cause them to become empty once again.

Comment: yeah i have tried that and nothing happens.

Comment: OK, well, let me ask you this: since this isn't actually a static table (its label texts come and go, its text field contents get emptied, etc. etc.), why did you make it a static table? It seems to me that that just makes things harder for you.

Comment: I used a static table due to having multiple UILabels and UITextFields in each row of different sizes and not in uniform. So would’ve been very difficult for me to achieve this design programmatically, something i was able to achieve very quickly with a static table. The only thing i needed which I wasn’t able to achieve was to have a button that reloads everything on the screen. A lot of the decision was due to this particular design i needed.